# normal hexadecimal to 0x hexadecimal conversion in oracle

Tags: oracle

i am using rawtohex to convert clob data to hexadecimal value as below:

```
SELECT RAWTOHEX(to_char(substr(fmla_txt,1, 4000))) as result FROM 
pmry_fmla_flng where WKSTN_OID_SH = 100 and WKSTN_OID_LNG = 2650;
```

getting the proper result as well, but the result i am getting as:

```
535445503109200920093C3C542E455854524150203120464C443E.....
```

but i want the result as:

```
0x535445503109200920093C3C542E455854524150203120464C443E.....
```

starting with 0x and the same will be not handle for null value, means for null it should come as null only not the 0x

please suggest and help me how to do.

Comment: You want it as a string (`VARCHAR`) then?

Answer (score 0):

How about concatenating '0x' to the return value of RAWTOHEX()?
Eg

```
create table test_ as
select sys_guid() raw_
from dual
connect by level <= 5 ;


SQL> describe test_ ;
Name Null? Type         
---- ----- ------------ 
RAW_       RAW(16 BYTE) 

select '0x' || rawtohex( raw_ ) from test_  ;

'0X'||RAWTOHEX(RAW_)                
0x7E7AFA5519563B89E0530100007F6AE4  
0x7E7AFA5519573B89E0530100007F6AE4  
0x7E7AFA5519583B89E0530100007F6AE4  
0x7E7AFA5519593B89E0530100007F6AE4  
0x7E7AFA55195A3B89E0530100007F6AE4  

5 rows selected.
```

For processing the NULL values, you could use CASE.

```
insert into test_ ( raw_ ) 
select null 
from dual 
connect by level <= 3 ;

select 
  case 
   when raw_ is not null then '0x' || rawtohex( raw_ )  
  end hex
from test_  ;

HEX                                 
0x7E7AFA5519563B89E0530100007F6AE4  
0x7E7AFA5519573B89E0530100007F6AE4  
0x7E7AFA5519583B89E0530100007F6AE4  
0x7E7AFA5519593B89E0530100007F6AE4  
0x7E7AFA55195A3B89E0530100007F6AE4  
NULL                                
NULL                                
NULL
```